# get all data from firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started to use firebase   and I am new to the node.js environment
im trying to send to get data from my database  i got this using this code

```
 var country = sessionStorage.countryname;
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/country/' + country + '/')

 ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(keysSnapshot) {
         var keys = keysSnapshot.val();

         console.log('keys', keys);

     })
 });
```

I got all the data in keys but i dont know how to access it for example i want to get the age and first_name of each post  ..this is what i get in console log

[image: console.log]

And this is my database 
[image: database]

this is the json code

```
{
  "country" : {
    "Algeria" : {
      "844kh2QXDHgw7i4KBvULpCSO5KE2" : {
        "-L9MvZxV2bVjcuKGZx-2" : {

          "age" : "26",
          "first_name" : "jack",

          "gender" : "female",

          "home_adress" : "2222222222222222222222222222",

          "last_name" : "anonyo",

        },
        "-L9Mvpnyx1f9DDDygJcG" : {

          "age" : "29",

          "first_name" : "jazmine",

          "gender" : "female",

          "home_adress" : "2222222222222222222222222222",

          "last_name" : "anony",

        }
      },
      "QgWbVLqInga3JRNuzzlZBCzwkws2" : {
        "-L9ES58GkQcZGywqpIWY" : {

          "age" : "29",

          "first_name" : "jazmine",

          "gender" : "female",

          "home_adress" : "2222222222222222222222222222",

          "last_name" : "anony",

        }
      }
    },

    "england" : {
      "jdL079kwJUQSBzKE7aNIPInPEHX2" : {
        "-L925-sxlxsF5k9LZFHp" : {

           "age" : "29",

          "first_name" : "jessica",

          "gender" : "female",

          "home_adress" : "2222222222222222222222222222",

          "last_name" : "anony",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please place the json  in the question.

Comment: ok i will export it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok this is how i got it working  var country = sessionStorage.countryname;

```
database.ref('posts/country/'+country).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var country = snapshot.key ;

  snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot1) {
    console.log(snapshot1.key); // 
    snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot2) {
      console.log(snapshot2.key); // 

      snapshot2.forEach(function(snapshot3) {
        console.log(snapshot3.key);
        console.log(snapshot3.val().first_name)
    });
  });
});
});
```

thanks to frank answer here [How to retrieve nested child value in Firebase database using javaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909588/how-to-retrieve-nested-child-value-in-firebase-database-using-javascript)
    ty for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate all your users:

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(keys);
for(x=0; x < objectKeys.length; x++){
     var currentKey = objectKeys[x];
     var userData = keys.currentKey; //Here you have all the data
     console.log(userData);
     //Now access the first_name property
     var firstName = userData.first_name;
}
```

I have no test it but it should work.

Comment: doesnt bro i added your code under the console log. i get data undefined

Comment: i put your code under     console.log('keys', keys); right? if so, it gives me this error : Cannot read property 'firts_name' of undefined

Comment: @SandraLopez what is the output int the console for userData?

Comment: i get undefined

Comment: i get the  console.log("objectKeys"); but the  userData undefined

Answer (score 0):

Get it with `snapshot.val()[844kh2QXDHgw7i4KBvULpCSO5KE2][-L9MvZxV2bVjcuKGZx-2][age]`. See documentation [Read and Write Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

> ```
> var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
> starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
>   updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
> });
> ```

Comment: var country = sessionStorage.countryname; var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/country/' + country + '/')
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { var age=snapshot.val().age; alert(age);   updateref(postElement, snapshot.val());}); i get undefined

Comment: try and take that trailing `+ '/') ` off there. Case matters, make sure you `.toLowercase()` before saving data. ..double check case.

Comment: same bro it gives me undefined , maybe i need something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909588/how-to-retrieve-nested-child-value-in-firebase-database-using-javascript it gives me childSnapshot is not defined when i try this answer T.T

Comment: try `snapshot.val()[844kh2QXDHgw7i4KBvULpCSO5KE2][-L9MvZxV2bVjcuKGZx-2][age]`

Comment: i got it working imma put the answer ty for help bro !